# Binance order: Timestamp for this request was 1000ms ahead of the server's time

Tags: python, datetime, cryptoapi, binance-api-client

I am writing some Python code to create an order with the Binance API:

```
from binance.client import Client

client = Client(API_KEY, SECRET_KEY)

client.create_order(symbol='BTCUSDT',
                    recvWindow=59999, #The value can't be greater than 60K
                    side='BUY',
                    type='MARKET',
                    quantity = 0.004)
```

Unfortunately I get the following error message:

```
"BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-1021): Timestamp for this request was 1000ms ahead of the server's time."
```

I already checked the difference (in miliseconds) between the Binance server time and my local time:

```
import time
import requests
import json
url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v1/time"
t = time.time()*1000
r = requests.get(url)

result = json.loads(r.content)

print(int(t)-result["serverTime"]) 

OUTPUT: 6997
```

It seems that the recvWindow of 60000 is still not sufficient (but it may not exceed 60K). I still get the same error.
Does anybody know how I can solve this issue?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe your problem is date and time in your computer. Your second code gives me negative value `-250` but you have positive value

Comment: [documentation](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#timing-security) shows `if (timestamp < (serverTime + 1000) && (serverTime - timestamp) <= recvWindow) {` which can rewrite as `(serverTime - recvWindow) <= timestamp < (serverTime + 1000)` and maybe your `timestamp`  satisfies `(serverTime - recvWindow) <= timestamp` but not satisfies `timestamp < (serverTime + 1000)` - and this can be in your error `Timestamp for this request was 1000ms ahead of the server's time`

Comment: you can writeh `timestamp < (serverTime + 1000)` as  `timestamp - serverTime < 1000` which is te same as your `int(t)-result["serverTime"]` but you get `6997` and this is not satisfies `6997 < 1000` As for me you have to correct clock/time in your system. OR maybe you need faster connection.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Probably the PC's time is out of sync.

You can do it using Windows -> Setting-> Time & Language -> Date & Time -> 'Sync Now'.

Screenshot:

[image: I share the picture as well]

Comment: Thank you for this answer, Is there any way to automate this on Python3 if needed?

Comment: As for the code, I don't know. I just found such solution while writing app

Comment: this works, but I have to repeat the process. Is there a way to permanently sync in windows 11 ?

Comment: You could use `w32tm /resync` (needs to be run as administrator) or set the automated sync time lower: w32tm /resync

Answer (score 2):

Manually set your clock back 1 second, ensure that ALL time updates are off. Daylights savings, autosync etc.

Answer (score 2):

I actually used the accepted solution as it is desirable to have the correct windows time in any event.

Nevertheless, here is an alternative code solution (which makes a Binance class and computes the time offset) for the same:

```py
import time
from binance.client import Client

class Binance:
    def __init__(self, public_key = '', secret_key = '', sync = False):
        self.time_offset = 0
        self.b = Client(public_key, secret_key)

        if sync:
            self.time_offset = self._get_time_offset()

    def _get_time_offset(self):
        res = self.b.get_server_time()
        return res['serverTime'] - int(time.time() * 1000)

    def synced(self, fn_name, **args):
        args['timestamp'] = int(time.time() - self.time_offset)
        return getattr(self.b, fn_name)(**args)
```

and then call function like this:

```
binance = Binance(public_key = 'my_pub_key', secret_key = 'my_secret_key', sync=True)
binance.synced('order_market_buy',  symbol='BNBBTC', quantity=10)
```

The link to the full thread is here: https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/issues/249

Answer (score 0):

Binance server time is behind your server time, because Binance servers do not sync often with ntp servers.

Workaround:

```
binance.setTimeOffset(-1000); // -1 sec
```

its if you use: npm binance

Answer (score 0):

For C#, I created this method to run command line to resync time on windows before running an API on `Binance`:

```
public static void ResyncWindowsTime()
{
    var commands = new List<string>() 
    { 
        "net stop w32time",
        "w32tm /unregister",
        "w32tm /register",
        "net start w32time",
        "w32tm /resync"
    };

    var process = new Process();
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;

    foreach (var command in commands)
    {
        startInfo.Arguments = "/C " + command;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on linux!

I had the same problem in kali linux on a python trading application i am learning to develop!

When logging the error info warnings and debug logs running the main.py file I get this response intially!

```
***

2023-04-10 02:53:10,945 ERROR :: Error while making GET request to /fapi/v1/account/: {'code': -1021, 'msg': "Timestamp for this request was 1000ms ahead of the server's time."} (error code 400)
2023-04-10 02:53:10,949 INFO :: Binance Futures Client successfully initialized

***
```

Setting the time on Linux is not the procedure for windows and I am still exploring that option!

This worked for me by following this in the command prompt!

Enter `timedatectl`:

```
┌──(a37trillion㉿localhost)-[~]
└─$ timedatectl
               Local time: Mon 2023-04-10 04:07:50 UTC
           Universal time: Mon 2023-04-10 04:07:50 UTC
                 RTC time: Mon 2023-04-10 04:07:48
                Time zone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: inactive
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

The NTP service was inactive, so setting the value to true will correct the time:

```
┌──(a37trillion㉿localhost)-[~]
└─$ sudo timedatectl set-ntp true                 
[sudo] password for a37trillion:
```

Double-check to make sure it's active:

```
┌──(a37trillion㉿localhost)-[~]
└─$ timedatectl
               Local time: Mon 2023-04-10 04:09:19 UTC
           Universal time: Mon 2023-04-10 04:09:19 UTC
                 RTC time: Mon 2023-04-10 04:09:19
                Time zone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
┌──(a37trillion㉿localhost)-[~]
└─$
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the following script as `SyncWindowsTimeWithBinance.ps1` and run it as administrator. It gets the current datetime from Binance, adds the timezone difference (+4 here), and adjusts (synchronizes) the Windows time accordingly.

```powershell
# Fetch server time from Binance API
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/time"
$serverTime = $response.serverTime

# Convert server time (milliseconds since Unix epoch) to DateTime
$epoch = Get-Date -Date "01/01/1970" -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0
$serverDateTime = $epoch.AddMilliseconds($serverTime)

# Adjust to timezone +4
$desiredDateTime = $serverDateTime.AddHours(4)

# Format the date and time
$formattedDateTime = Get-Date -Date $desiredDateTime -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

# Set the system's date and time (requires administrative privileges)
Set-Date -Date $formattedDateTime
```

It is useful when Windows time synchronization is not working or you want to synchronize data with the help of code.